# Android - Is it possible to programatically disable certain functionality?

Tags: android

Are the following actions possible using the latest version of the Android API?:

1. Temporarily disable sending text messages
2. Temporarily disable receiving text messages

   *Ideally, I would intercept them and queue them up for later delivery.
3. Temporarily disable incoming calls except from certain phone numbers
4. Temporarily disable outgoing calls except to certain phone numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn on airplane mode, which disables all radios.

Beyond that, none of what you wish to do appears possible from an ordinary Android application.

Comment: Hrm. That's a shame.So getting a ServiceState object and calling SetState(STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY) wouldn't restrict inc/out calls or messages? 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html

Comment: You can try that -- I hadn't looked there (too many classes with settings, too little time). I suspect, though, that you need a permission that only firmware applications can have. But, that's just a guess.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and post the results.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer as I don't know when I'll get a chance to test this out. I'll post if the ServiceState object does indeed allow you to control this though. Thanks for the help.